# NativeScript : How can i open file dialog to select file from my phone

Tags: android, nativescript

I am Very new in mobile and native script development,

actually i am trying to upload a video file into you tube from my mobile gallery, but before Posting this to you-tube environment, i need a file selector (open file gallery dialog) which will show all videos in my phone

I think there are no plug-in for this.not sure writing native code for this is only option ?? if yes please assist me how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might well be a better way, but one approach would be to use the [File System Plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/file-system). This way you could enumerate all the files in the documents directory, check if they are videos and then push them to an array e.g.:

```
var fileArray = [];
var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
documents.eachEntity(function (entity) {
    console.log(entity.name);
    if (entity.name.search('.mpeg') !== -1 {
         fileArray.push(entity);
    }
    // Return true to continue, or return false to stop the iteration.
    return true;
});
```

You then have an array of the file options which you could quite easily build a UI to display. However, I think maybe you want a native UI for the documents system, which I have not come across as yet.

However, contributing the feature to the File System Plugin might not be too difficult.